# Set Default Route for a Controller as Index View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have the url:

```
www.mywebsite/signup/index
```

That works fine.

What I want to do is add a new route mapping to the RouteConfig class that allows the following url to work:

```
www.mywebsite/signup
```

I have tried:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Signup",
        url: "{controller}/",
        defaults: new { controller = "Signup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

And:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Signup",
        url: "{controller}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Signup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

And:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Signup",
        url: "{controller}/*",
        defaults: new { controller = "Signup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

My RouteConfig class has been customized and the default routing when creating a new ASP.NET MVC Project has been changed, it currently looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultConstrained",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = ConstrollersAsCSV() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SiteLogin",
            url: "{site}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", site = "" },
            constraints: new { site = new ExcludeAndUseRegex() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Where the constraint method ConstrollersAsCSV (which I don't know what that is doing) is:

```
public static string ConstrollersAsCSV(string optional = null)
    {
        var list = GetControllerNames();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("(");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(optional))
            sb.Append(optional);

        foreach (var cont in list)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 1)
                sb.Append("|");
            sb.Append(cont.Replace("Controller", ""));
        }
        sb.Append(")");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

And the implementation of GetControllerNames is:

```
public static List<string> GetControllerNames()
    {
        List<string> controllerNames = new List<string>();
        GetSubClasses<Controller>().ForEach(
            type => controllerNames.Add(type.Name.ToLower()));
        GetSubClasses<ApiController>().ForEach(
            type => controllerNames.Add(type.Name.ToLower()));

        controllerNames.Add("elmah");

        return controllerNames;
    }
```

And the implementation of GetSubClasses is:

```
    private static List<Type> GetSubClasses<T>()
    {
        return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
            type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))).ToList();
    }
```

The error I am getting when going to www.mywebsite.com/signup is:

```
**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**
```

Comment: The default MVC routing should already handle both of these cases.

Comment: If your controller is SignupController then you do not have to handle that situation. MVC will handle it handle for you. Because Index is default method for all controllers.

Comment: Please see my updated question, another developer has changed the default routing that is setup when you create a new ASP.NET MVC project.